# Change culture of kendo grid

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, telerik-grid, culture

How do I change the text in filter of grid? I've tried to import culture in head

```
<script src="kendo/js/cultures/kendo.culture.co-FR.min.js"></script>
```

and to add script to body

```
<script>
        kendo.culture("co-FR");
</script>
```

But the filter text is still English. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1):

kendo culture defines specific information for the number formats, week and month names, date and time formats and etc, it doesn't provide languaje internationalization.

You could try language packs for Telerik's Kendo UI https://github.com/loudenvier/kendo-global I guess they are unofficial (not maintained by telerik), and some languages are not complete.